# LNK1105 не удается закрыть файл "E:\Lab_10\Debug\Lab_10.exe"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

Кусок кода, который вызывает ошибку. При удалении папки debug ошибка исчезает, но только на один запуск программы. Функция получает на вход строку char* и выводит кол-во слов в ней. Задание по лабораторной работе.

```
int word_count(const char* str) 
{

    int cnt = 0;
    bool flag = false;

    for (const char* p = str+1; *p != 0; ++p) {

        if (*p == ' ' &&  *(p - 1) != ' ' && *(p + 1) != ' ' && *(p + 1) != 0) cnt += 1;
        if (*p != ' ') flag = true;

    }

    if (flag) cnt += 1;

    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Перед сборкой останавливайте запущенной приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Во время сборки не завершена работа предыдущей версии программы, так что .exe-файл заблокирован от записи, на что и жалуется компоновщик.

Убедитесь, что предыдущий запуск программы завершен.